# Flutter: Why do we need to dispose ViewModels?

Tags: flutter, optimization, viewmodel, dispose

Can someone give a simple case where we will immidiately appreciate the importance of disposing viewmodels and at the same time know the repercussions if we don't?
My App is running fine without all these disposing stuff, I really just don't understand the vague "prevent memory leak" stuff.

Comment: What kind of ViewModel? Do you work with provider (ChangeNotifierProvider, etc.), another package from pub.dev, your own implementation? Can you show us some snippets?

Comment: @OzanTaskiran I mean viewModels in general, why there are cases that we need to dispose them? yes, I'm using provider under the hood - stacked architecture

Comment: Your app will continue to run fine, until it doesn't... It's like, I don't have to worry what things cost to buy, as long as I have plenty of money.

Answer (score 0):

Disposing the resources is important when flutter says this to do  because if these resources are not disposed they will remain alive and keep consuming system resources like memory, processor etc and may produce unwanted result or Null/Memory Exceptions, also it can slow down (JANK) your APP as Flutter main thread is a single thread.

Resources Like Timer if you do not cancel the time it will remain active.

Answer (score 0):

Your devices have a certain number of resources.  Not disposing objects leaves them in memory, in the worst case "out of memory" errors occur. Therefore you should always take care to avoid memory leaks.

Among them e.g. timers, animations, controllers, etc.